# Two different video streams on PC. How do I sent each video stream into a separate monitor?

Tags: software-recommendation, software, hardware, output

[image: Example]

For example, in the picture I have video stream A and video stream B. How can I sent each video stream into separate video outputs, so that each video stream can be sent to its own monitor or video capture device?

Please note, I am not looking to extend the display as used in the Windows 10 display settings.